# How do I extract files directly to a hidden directory in Linuxmint?

Tags: linux-mint, archive

I am using Archive Manager 3.16.5 in Linux Mint and now I want to extract files directly to a hidden directory (say .vim) but I can't find hidden files/directory listed in the gui. So how do I go about it without having to use the terminal?

Comment: Is you question, "How do I view hidden files in Archive Manager"?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes, that was my question, but I have since figured it out. `Ctrl+H` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. `Ctrl+H` will show hidden files.